# Magento Custom Address Attribute in Back-end

Tags: php, mysql, magento, custom-attributes

I have created a customer address attribute in Magento called 'addresstype' that is a varchar with radio options of 'Residential' and 'Business' on the front-end.

The attribute is saved during checkout and appears in the database.  Customers can edit their profiles and I can actively pull the variables using `$address->getAddresstype();` to check the appropriate radio button.

My only problem is that in the back-end on individual sales order pages, the variable is not coming through.  I have edited /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Renderer/Default.php (using `$address->getAddresstype()`) and can see the attribute in the array using `print_r($attributes = Mage::helper('customer/address')->getAttributes());`

It is marked as 'is_visible' in the database as well.

Answer (score 4):

This is because the sales order / invoice pages pull the information back from different tables (sales_flat_order_address). Assuming you have it in the right place in the first time (which it seems you do), then you just need to make Magento copy the correct information over.

```
<fieldsets>
    <sales_convert_quote_address>
        <your_attribute>
            <to_order>*</to_order>
        </your_attribute>
</fieldsets>
```

You might also have to add another field set value in to copy the value from the address to the quote address, off the top of my head I can't remember. If you search Magento's code for fieldsets in *.xml you should find examples.

Comment: You're right.  I added the column to the flat order table.  I already had the fieldsets in my config.xml file.  The attribute is still not saving to the database during checkout.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you flushed the cache in System > Cache Management? Click both buttons.